# Synchronizaton Object Lock Confusion

Tags: java, multithreading

I am studying K&B threads chapter. I was reading about synchronization. Here is an example from
K&B.

```
public class AccountDanger implements Runnable {
  private Account account = new Account();
  public void run() {
    for(int x =0 ; x < 5 ; x++){
      makeWithdrawl(10);
      if(account.getBalance() < 0 ){
        System.out.println("account is overdrawn");
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    AccountDanger accountDanger = new AccountDanger();
    Thread one = new Thread(accountDanger);
    Thread two = new Thread(accountDanger);
    one.setName("Fred");
    two.setName("Lucy");
    one.start();
    two.start();
  }

  private synchronized void makeWithdrawl(int amt){
    if(account.getBalance() >= amt){
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is going to withdraw");

    try{
      Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    account.withdraw(amt);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " completes the withdrawl");
   }
    else{
      System.out.println("Not enough in account for " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " to withdraw " +
        account.getBalance());
    }
 }
}
```

K&B talks about synchronized methods and synchronized blocks. Here is referring paragraph from K&B.

> When a method is executing code from within synchronized block, code
>   is said to be executing in a synchronized context. When you
>   synchronize a method, the object used to invoke the method is the
>   object whose lock must be acquired. But when we synchronize block of
>   code, you must specify which object's lock you want to use as a lock.

So in this example, will the lock be acquired on AccountDanger instance or Account object?
I think so it should be AccountDanger. Am i perceiving correct? If it is AccountDanger object,
and one thread has got the lock of AccountDanger, will any other thread be able to call non-synchronized methods?

Comment: Yes, it's on the AccountDanger object (implicitly because the method has the synchronized keyword).

Comment: Thanks kayaman. So does it mean while one thread has acquired lock of the current object, no other thread can access any other non-synchronized methods?

Comment: No. It means that other threads can't access other synchronized methods. Non-synchronized methods can be accessed, since they're not being guarded by an object monitor.

Answer (score 0):

> So in this example, will the lock be acquired on AccountDanger
>   instance or Account object?

Yes. One trick I've seen used a lot is to synchronize on `this` when you have only a small block of code that actually needs to be synchronized. For example:

```
int balance = -1;
synchronized(this) {
  balance = account.getBalance();
  account.withdraw(amt);
}
//IO, etc. after that.
```

In general this speeds things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
private synchronized void makeWithdrawl(int amt){
     //is implicitly acquiring lock on this object (AccountDanger object)              
}
```

So in the example the first thread to call this method will enter the `synchronized` block acquiring `this` object monitor and holds it and no other thread except the first thread itself can acquire the monitor lock again on `this`. All the other threads that call this method will block until the first thread releases the lock and frees the monitor.

Note: Locks used for synchronized blocks are [Re-entrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787957/reentrant-synchronization-behavior-with-synchronized-statements) in nature.